# read xlsx file with background to df and transfrom df to xlsx with background also

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, background

I'm self learning python and  while writing some program I had a struggle with reading xlsx file with its background.
As I found nothing that can help me on the internet, I'm here to ask..

So, I have a xlsx file that contains many rows and each row has background with specific color.
I have to delete some of the rows from the df and convert df to xlsx file.
I already wrote scrip that does it all, except is cannot read cells with background.
So the output xlsx file has no background colors at all.

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: have you looked into the `openpyxl` module this can set colors for you check out the `.styles_Color` function specifically.

Comment: found nothing about how to preserve the style of the original xlsx file

Comment: I've had a nose but not been able to find anything, that said I only looked for a few minutes, asfar as I know this is not possible in pandas but should be possible with openpyxl or xlwings. another option is to open the .xml file and find the colors within that?